# Git push to two remotes and have them sync

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

This is one of those thing that I'm sure I'm missing a easy step but maybe you can give me a bit of help.

We use a git repository that matches up with our development environment  and we develop locally.

As the procedure goes now,  you push your changes git from your local repo,  then go pull them into the development site, and away we go everything is synced.  I am trying to eliminate the step were we log into the remote environment and pull.

So i attempted a double push which worked like a charm.  Except on the test environment we now have `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/live' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)` Although they match up equally in commits.   Is there a way to cure that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks.

1. Configure a listener process on your test site server, which will initiate a pull and then do whatever testing magic you want.
2. Configure Bitbucket to notify that listener process when certain conditions are met - for example, when a user pushes new commits.
3. Push commits. As long as you have things working properly, Bitbucket will notify your test server, which will pull code and then do the nifty testing things that you didn't really specify here.

There's a bit more documentation at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html which might help. I think the real trick will be setting up the listener, though, and a lot of that is going to depend on the specific details of your setup.